# How to write this Query in LINQ

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I have one LINQ query with foreach loop. Everything is fine. But it takes more time to get the value. So anybody suggest me how can i do this in LINQ query itself.

**Code**

```
NormValue = "";
c = 0;
var NormValuelist = db.BCont.Where(x => x.BId == BId && x.TNo == Tag).ToList();
foreach (var item in NormValuelist)
{
    if (c == 0)
        NormValue = item.NormValue;
    else
        NormValue += " " + item.NormValue;
    c = 1;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite this query with `string.Join` to avoid creating multiple `string` objects in a loop, like this:

```
string NormValue = string.Join(" ", db.BCont.Where(x => x.BId == BId && x.TNo == Tag));
```

The number of round-trips to DB will remain the same, but the creation of `List<string>` and the partially concatenated `string` objects will be optimized out.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `String.Join`, you could also use `Enumerable.Aggregate`:

```
var NormValueList = 
    db.BCont.Where(x => x.Bid == BId && x.TNo == Tag)
            .Select(x => x.NormValue)
            .Aggregate((s, x) => s + " " + x);
```

Comment: How can i use this in a model .. I am trying to use like this .. **BTags = Db.BibContents.Where(x => x.BibId == q.BibId && x.TagNo == "245").Aggregate((s, x) => s + " " + x.NormValue)** .. but showing error. Btags is a string type model property.

Comment: @UniqueChar - I updated my answer. Unfortunately I'm only guessing about the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having large items in "NormValuelist" then it would be better to use StringBuilder instead of string(NormValue)